# How should we [structure] the burnination of this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/structure) tag:

> Structure is a fundamental, tangible or intangible notion referring to the recognition, observation, nature, and permanence of patterns and relationships of entities

Which is to say: not even the people who wrote the tag description know what this tag is for.

To show that this meets the burnination requirements:

- This tag is so vague as to be meaningless.
- I suppose that it *could* refer to on-topic questions, but it refers to all kinds of off-topic questions, too.
- It's too vague to add any meaningful information.
- It decidedly does *not* mean the same thing in all of the common contexts.

Comment: If [tag:structure] is burniated, some of the 4,826 questions tagged with it may benefit by being re-tagged with [tag:data-structures] or [tag:struct].

Comment: That's a horrible tag wiki excerpt.  I suggest a wiki-edit ban for all those responsible for that crime.  Then we can figure out if we can give the tag a meaningful description; if not then the tag should die too.

Comment: @BenVoigt As a mitigating circumstance, I would mention that the last edit happened in 2015, and it wasn't a significantly below average quality at the time.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree completely - I'm inclined to think that this tag is irredeemably bad, though - I can't think of a way to describe it that wouldn't be wildly vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @peterh: That wiki didn't meet our standards in 2015 either: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/

Comment: @BenVoigt Possible, I am talking here not about the written things, but as I can remember the mean tag description quality.

Comment: @peterh: I think that's a different topic entirely, related to 'Taxonomist' and related editing and reviewing badges, that rewarded people for dumping plagiarized crap into wikis.  And if people are using broken windows to justify garbage, that makes it even more critical to sweep it away and stop the people bringing it here.

Comment: @BenVoigt I only tried to say that this tagwiki was not so bad - at the time, relative to the others, at the time.

Comment: Puns be fun, but the title on this one misleads... without the tag reference, it would be a perfectly valid discussion to have on Meta. How many questions are we talking about here? Are the questions themselves on-topic, or has the tag become a trash magnet?

Comment: @Mogsdad I edited the title to be less confusing.

Comment: @Mogsdad It's 4,499 open questions. Some garbage but not nearly as bad as [documentation] or [api] as far as I can tell.

Comment: Interestingly, Wikimedia seems to [have copied the text for their pictures of *structure*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Structure&diff=123267857&oldid=100883300), but none of the images seem to have anything to do with coding...